# Use expressions instead of variables in azure devops

Tags: variables, azure-devops

In azure devops, inside the classic build, I can generally do `$(myVar)` to get the value of a variable in certain places. I am not sure if that particular usage has a name.

Is there a way to pass an expression for the same use cases. I mean instead of `$(myVar)` can I do something like `$(coalesce(myVar, otherVar))`? 
I have tried wrapping it in different brackets, doesn't seem to work.

I have checked the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops

It doesn't show how to use in the classic pipelines, only yaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to pass an expression for the same use cases. I mean instead of $(myVar) can I do something like $(coalesce(myVar,
>   otherVar))?

Agree with **Daniel**, the common use of Expressions is to **define conditions** for a step, job, or stage or **define variables**. The expressions work well in Yaml pipelines while it's not supported in Classic pipelines if you want to define variables using `$(coalesce(myVar, otherVar))` instead of `$(myVar)`.

The `$(coalesce(...))`is one of the [built-in functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#functions). The only working scope of those functions in classic pipelines is conditions for Job/Task, see:

Job:

[image]

Task:

[image]

But it seems you're trying to use built-in functions when defining variables, for now that's not supported in classic pipelines. Those can only be used to define/control the conditions for job/task in classic pipelines.

Comment: Yeah this makes sens. I too was using custom conditions as a work around. it just adds more tasks. Which is why I was trying use an inline expression.

Comment: Didn't realize you could use custom condition in tasks too. That really simplified the process, so I am marking this as the answer. I'll look more into YAML in future

Answer (score 1):

Expressions as outlined in the documentation you linked **only** apply to YAML. You won't be able to do what you want to do unless you use YAML.

Comment: Odd. I have used it in certain places in the classic definitions as well.

Answer (score 1):

While using expressions in classic pipelines is not supported (except in the control section of the task), I've had success **defining a release variable with the expression, and using that release variable** instead.

In my case I wanted to do releases based on git tags, and extract the version number from the tag.

Variable definition (with the expression I want to use):

[image]

Using the variable in the task:

[image]